# NSLayoutConstraints to limit label width

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am struggling to set the necessary constraints to limit the width of a label to the leading anchor of a button in a tableview cell.

**Desired Result**

Label to the left, button to the right. Label wraps before button if needed.

[image]

**Current Result**

The label is pulling the red button to the left.

[image]

**Code**

```
[button.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cell.contentView.centerYAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
[button.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cell.contentView.trailingAnchor constant:-5].active = YES;

[label.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cell.contentView.leadingAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
[label.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:button.leadingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
```

I have tried various things like adding another label constraint to the right of the cell but that squeezed the button (I tried to fix by setting its compression resistance priority but that had no effect)

What constraints do I need to achieve the desired result please?

Comment: This should be all you need: `[button setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
[label.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:button.leadingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
```

into

```
[label.trailingAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor:button.leadingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
```

[image]

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

  lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let val = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
    val.dataSource = self
    val.delegate = self
    val.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    val.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    return val
  }()

  let data: [String] = [
    "LayoutDemo",
    "LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo LayoutDemo",
    "LayoutDemoLayoutDemoLayoutDemoLayoutDemo"
  ]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(tableView)
  }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    data.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCell else { fatalError() }
    cell.dataText = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
  }

}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

  var dataText: String? {
    didSet {
      label.text = dataText
    }
  }

  lazy var label: UILabel = {
    let val = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    val.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    val.numberOfLines = 0
    val.backgroundColor = .gray
    return val
  }()

  lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let val = UIButton(type: .custom)
    val.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    val.backgroundColor = .red
    return val
  }()

  override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    contentView.addSubview(label)
    contentView.addSubview(button)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
      button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
      button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
      button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),

      label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
      label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
      label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
      label.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: -10)
    ])

  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't understand the question, I think he wants to keep the position of the button fixed, then the label on the left adapts to the width and height, and there is a spacing between the button and label.